# Why $\left\| \begin{pmatrix} 0 &B\\ C &0 \end{pmatrix}\right\|\leq\left\| \begin{pmatrix} A &B\\ C &D \end{pmatrix}\right\|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;, \;\cdot\rangle$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and let $\mathcal{L}(E)$ the algebra of all operators on $E$.

> Let $A,B,C,D\in\mathcal{L}(E)$. I want to prove that
>   $$\left\| \begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &B\\
> C &0
> \end{pmatrix}\right\|\leq\left\| \begin{pmatrix}
> A &B\\
> C &D
> \end{pmatrix}\right\|.$$
>   Here $\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &B\\
> C &0
> \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
> A &B\\
> C &D
> \end{pmatrix}\in \mathcal{L}(E\oplus E)$.

I read this result in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-02/S0002-9939-05-07796-8/S0002-9939-05-07796-8.pdf) without citing any references.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left\| \pmatrix{-A & B\cr C & -D\cr}\right\|= \left\| \pmatrix{A & B\cr C & D\cr}\right\|$$
because $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$ is an isomorphism of $E \oplus E$, and
$$ \pmatrix{0 & B\cr C & 0\cr} = \frac{1}{2} \pmatrix{A & B\cr C & D\cr} + \frac{1}{2} \pmatrix{-A & B\cr C & -D\cr}$$